# Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt()

Tags: server-setup

I'm having quite some troubles hosting my Magento website. I've always ran websites (Joomla, Wordpress) on shared hosting. However, for this Magento website they advised a VPS.

After quite some work (PHP memory size was too low, etc.) the website does load, but I am unable to access the admin area:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt() in /var/www/elly/lib/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php on line 87 Call Stack: 0.0001 637816 1. {main}() /var/www/elly/index.php:0 0.0014 708040 2. Mage::run() /var/www/elly/index.php:87 0.0032
```

Can anyone help me out solving this?

---

I've got another question:
After adding a article to my shopping list, pages won't load anymore. Look for an example on: http://bit.ly/1cvXGKa

E.g.: Add an article from this page (http://bit.ly/HlmNAZ) by hovering it and clicking on 'In winkelwagen'.

Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: Considering you mentioned you have always used shared hosting in the past, I would highly suggest you not use a VPS and rather head over to Nexcess and signup for one of their [Magento Optimized](http://www.nexcess.net/magento-hosting#sip-share) shared hosting plans. Unless you're up for a major challenge… this is only the tip of the iceberg of things you'll run into self-administering being both new to Magento and VPS administration.

Comment: Or try Byte, it's a Dutch Magento hoster. They will set everything up for you and will make sure hosting wise your shop will be ready to go

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems there's no curl installed on your server. Check your `phpinfo()` for curl.
If not present, you or your provider can enable it in the PHP config:

`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` (or similar)

enable extension:

```
extension=curl.so
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked out. Sorry, I'm really a noob at this PHP.ini-file.

Answer (score 9):

I had same issue just install curl and restart your ngix or apache and php5

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to enable the `curl` extension for PHP.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I certainly am a 'noob' in this.

I connected through Terminal and succesfully entered these commands:
apt-get update
apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl

When I check, I'll get:
"php5-curl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded."

I guess it is installed now, but I still get the same error. Will I need to enable it somewhere?

Comment: hi, you may check your php.ini and add it there. See my updated answer