# Cant access local magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, admin-panel, link

As described in the title i am dealing with the following problem.

I took a back up of a Magento based site that I am currently working on, placed it in my `document root` folder and finally extracted it.

I can see the home page of the site, but when i try to gain access as administrator via Magento admin panel i get this message

> the requested url was not found on this server.

The above message is also displayed when a link is pressed..

Comment: Have you tried adding http://path-to-base-url/index.php/admin-link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your .htaccess. Probably URL Rewrites are not working. Open your `.htaccess` you will find a code `RewriteBase`

if your project is at the Root of the server you should put

```
RewriteBase /
```

If it is in the subfolder suppose `test` then your rewrite base should be

```
RewriteBase /test/
```

Comment: i did what you proposed and some links started to work.I also entered my credentials to access admin panel but i am encoutering this message "Call to undefined function curl_setopt()"

Comment: now i get this message "Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt()" on line 87.

Comment: It seems curl is not enabled on your server. Please check your server compatibility with Magento. You can check it from this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

Comment: i have just checked my compatibility with magento and the result was "Congratulations! Your server meets the requirements for Magento!". I have also used the following command sudo port install php53-curl, but the same error appeared again.

Comment: It is not possible for me to tell what exactly the problem can be. Could you please add more details and information regarding it so it will be possible for me to review it.

Comment: OS is irrelevant to your error

Comment: i am using mac os x yosemite(10.10.2) with php5.5.4, mysql server5.6.23, apache2.2.29, phpmyadmin 4.3.11.1, if you want something more tell me.

Comment: Check out this link it might help http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-curl-setopt

Comment: Dexter i want to thank you for your help so far, i found that post too and i already cheked it out.

Comment: There is one long way i can suggest. You can setup a fresh copy of mangento and check if the same error arrives. If yes, there is a problem with server if no, some of the files maybe missing. In this case you can try replacing the core files

Answer (score 0):

Look in your `app/etc/local.xml` what is under the admin section for frontName.

Maybe you have a custom name set here.